# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.ANTLRException but I have antlr-2.7.6 in folder lib of project

Tags: hibernate, classpath, antlr, classnotfoundexception

I have this in .classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    ...
    ...
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
    ...
</classpath>
```

Some .jar added. When I try this:

```
Query query2 = session.createQuery(sql2);
```

throw exception in question name:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.ANTLRException

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Greetings.

Comment: Same problem here, started after adding velocity, which uses struts-core, which uses antlr with another version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the Hibernate API. 
Hibernate 3.0 uses ANTLR (Another Tool for Language Recognition) for processing HSQL queries - if I remember correctly.
You need to add an additional jar (ANTLR-2.7.5H3.jar) to your classpath.

Or you can add the below maven dependency to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
<version>2.7.5H3</version>
</dependency>
```